# How to use Python Pip install software, to pull packages from Github?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a package from Github, using Pip, using the following syntax

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git#egg=FacebookSDK
```

and getting the error "cannot find command git". [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610639/78409) has (unchecked) answers saying that Git needs to be installed on the system. However, [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033897/python-package-install-using-pip-or-easy-install-from-repos/1625662#1625662) states that "Git, Subversion, Bazaar and Mercurial are all supported" by Pip.

The [Pip documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) also says it has "Native support for other version control systems (Git, Mercurial and Bazaar)".

So how do I install this package with Pip? I really *don't* want to install Git on my VPS. Or are there any non-Pip tools, for just pulling files from repositories (without doing a full Git install)?

**Update** - so I bit the bullet, and installed Git on my VPS. Pip still wasn't able to grab the package, but it was giving a *different* set of errors, so - progress. :) I finally did

```
git clone http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git
```

(note the `http`, not `https`), and manage to download the package, then just installed it manually.

Comment: Although pip 'supports git', it still needs the git client/programme in order to fetch the files.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8382819/14420) about bypassing git altogether by using the "download everything in a zipfile" option, `pip install https://github.com/example/some-cool-project/zipball/master`

Comment: Dunno who decided that "this question may already have an answer here", or that this is a duplicate question - but the other question was asked *two months* after mine. Wouldn't that make *it* the duplicate?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you would need the git client to be install on your machine. In the event that you don't have git installed, try this:

```
pip install https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/zipball/master
```

or

```
pip install https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tarball/master
```

---

You need to install the `git-core`, since the `git://` protocol isn't associated with anything.

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Comment: Using `https` only, didn't work. Also, *why* would I need to install the Git client? The docs state that it's a supported repository format.

Comment: I ran the same and got it to work. I'm not too sure of the underlying reason. I'm fairly confident that you would need git because `git://` isn't associated with anything. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610639/command-that-works-in-local-comuter-but-doesnt-work-in-server

Comment: I did already look at that link, it's the same one I linked - and none of the answers have a checkmark, or even *upvotes*. Plus, they contradict the documentation. Granted, it's possible the docs are wrong.

Comment: Yup, I noticed the same. I think what they meant to say is that it uses the git tool to fetch the source. Have the look their Git implementation: https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pip/src/c036c41fce72/pip/vcs/git.py. I don't see anything resembling a git protocol implementation to pull the sources. HTH.

Comment: So you're saying it isn't that the docs are wrong, but that I'm *reading* it wrong. :) You could be right - I was thinking *native support* meant it was self-contained, but maybe not. Sigh...

Comment: Written wrong / reading it wrong = all the same in this case since it doesn't work without the git-core or using a simple http connection. I've edited my answer reflect our conversation in the comments. Cheers!

Comment: broken url, `facebook/python-sdk` is gone; might https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk now?

Answer (score 6):

For Windows or none git users:

1. I first download and unpack the file.
2. Then in the python directory going to \Scripts
3. Starting here the command prompt (shift + rigth-click)
4. `pip install C:\Theano-master`
   *# replace Theano-master with the path to your directory of your package

Comment: I would just mention to replace the C:\Theano-master with the filepath location of the module.

Answer (score 1):

This morning, when I run python pip to install a pcakge from git has problems.
`pip install git+https://github.com/gumblex/zhconv.git#egg=zhconv`
Firstly get error msg:
`ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?`
Try `pip install git`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git
```

When I find this question,tried answers from @Mridang Agarwalla not work for first one; for second cmd, there was "time out" to git site.

But when trying answer from @Martijn van Wezel, it is very successfully. Thanks! @Martijn van Wezel

My trying is:

1. download the Zip file i need from Git page and extract it to a folder.
   https://github.com/gumblex/zhconv
   extract the ZIP to my local folder: D:\gitPackageforinstall\zhconv
2. Then success by below cmd.
   `pip install D:\gitPackageforinstall\zhconv`

Hope this could be a reference to others as an update for 20210419

Answer (score -3):

I'm learning about PostgreSQL and had to install the windows version. It was suggested to use git+, and I was running to the same issues that John C was experiencing.

Martijn above recommended unpacking and downloading. That is also what the creators of win-psycopg suggested. So I thought I'd share their method for installing into a Virtual Environment.

Thank you stickpeople: 
http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

To install into a virtual env: [image: Pretty neat]