# Configuring so that pip install can work from github

Tags: python, git, pip

We'd like to use pip with github to install private packages to our production servers.  This question concerns what needs to be in the github repo in order for the install to be successful.

Assuming the following command line (which authenticates just fine and tries to install):

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/BlahCo/search/tree/prod_release_branch/ProductName
```

What needs to reside in the ProductName?  Is it the contents of what would normally be in the tar file after running setup.py with the sdist option, or is the actual tar.gz file, or something else?

I'm asking here because I've tried several variations and can't make it work.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

You need the whole python package, with a `setup.py` file in it.

A package named `foo` would be:

```
foo # the installable package
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
└── setup.py
```

And install from github like:

```
$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/foo.git
or
$ pip install git+https://github.com/myuser/foo.git@v123
or
$ pip install git+https://github.com/myuser/foo.git@newbranch
```

More info at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Comment: The above works, thank you very much.  But what if I have releases in a subdir within a repo, so rather than foo.git I'm looking for foo/releases/ProductVer .  Is that possible and if so how?  Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: No, it is not possible. pip only installs from root repository directory, at least for git. Don't know how subversion behaves...

Comment: If you want to do this over ssh and private repos, [this is a post on how to do that](http://jtushman.github.io/blog/2013/06/17/sharing-code-across-applications-with-python/)

Comment: Why is it that you did not pass the `-e` option (editable mode) to pip?

Comment: @user815423426 because I don't want it to be an `editable` installation. For more details take a look at http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode

Comment: Here's the new url scheme: `pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pip.git`

Source: [pip Github repo](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/539#issuecomment-5825986)

Comment: @ccgillett It's a long time later, but there is a way to specify a subfolder: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments

Comment: `setup.py` is depreciated and `pyproject.toml` is the [canonical approach](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/). The [documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) advises on construction of the `pyproject.toml`. The `pyproject.toml` should be in the repo root, with a `src` subdirectory which contains a `foo` (module name) subdirectory, which then contains the `__init__.py` and other Python files. You may want a `py.typed` (empty file) in with the code to support [PEP-561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/). That should be enough.

Answer (score 120):

I had similar issue when I had to install from github repo, but did not want to install git , etc.

The simple way to do it is using zip archive of the package. Add `/zipball/master` to the repo URL:

```
    $ pip install https://github.com/hmarr/django-debug-toolbar-mongo/zipball/master
Downloading/unpacking https://github.com/hmarr/django-debug-toolbar-mongo/zipball/master
  Downloading master
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://github.com/hmarr/django-debug-toolbar-mongo/zipball/master
Installing collected packages: django-debug-toolbar-mongo
  Running setup.py install for django-debug-toolbar-mongo
Successfully installed django-debug-toolbar-mongo
Cleaning up...
```

This way you will make pip work with github source repositories.

Comment: This is the only answer that also works under Windows

Comment: How can this be done with private repositories? (as the question asks)

Answer (score 35):

If you want to use `requirements.txt` file, you will need `git` and something like the entry below to anonymously fetch the master branch in your `requirements.txt`.

#### For regular install:

```
git+git://github.com/celery/django-celery.git
```

#### For "[editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e)" install:

```
-e git://github.com/celery/django-celery.git#egg=django-celery
```

Editable mode downloads the project's source code into `./src` in the current directory. It allows `pip freeze` to output the correct github location of the package.

Comment: where does that egg names comes from? it fails to load package in django after replacing pip package with github repo

Comment: @holms Lookup name in setup.py

Comment: What's `#egg=django-celery`? Is that a placeholder?

Comment: @enchance It's the package name.

Comment: I found `git+git://github.com` wouldn't work on Windows (pip had a failure when cloning) but `git+https://github.com` worked.

Answer (score 16):

Clone target repository same way like you cloning any other project:

```
git clone git@github.com:myuser/foo.git
```

Then install it in develop mode:

```
cd foo
pip install -e .
```

You can change anything you wan't and every code using `foo` package will use modified code.

There 2 benefits ot this solution:

1. You can install package in your home projects directory.
2. Package includes `.git` dir, so it's regular Git repository. You can push to your fork right away.

Comment: I can testify that this solution is magical. In my case, I wanted to hack on `pip`, so I cloned the `pip` repository, created a virtualenv, activated it, and did `pip install -e .`. Then the `pip` in the virtualenv was in development mode! I'm impressed that this works even with the package manager itself.

Comment: This is great! I notice that when I installed using this method and then run `pip list`, the package in question has references to the Git branch and absolute path from which it was installed. Does it keep any references to those or can the source be deleted?

Answer (score 6):

## Here is the simple solution

### With git

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git
```

### Without git

```
pip install https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/tarball/master
```

or

```
pip install https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/zipball/master
```

or

```
pip install https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/archive/master.zip
```

Note: You need a python package with the setup.py file in it.

Answer (score 2):

Below format could be use to install `python` libraries via `pip` from `GitHub`.

```
pip install <LibName>@git+ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<LibName>#egg<LibName>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way in Colab

```
!git clone https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers.git
!pip install -e /content/sentence-transformers
import sentence_transformers
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested *Optimized* **Ubuntu** Solution using the terminal command:

**Step 1:**
In a selected directory clone the git repo.

Example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/httpie/httpie.git
```

**Step 2:**
select/change path to the directory, to the cloned folder

```
$ cd ClonedFolderName
```

**Step 3:**
Enter following command to install that package

```
ColnedFolderName(directory Name) $ pip install ./
```

**pip install ./** is command to enter in cloned directory name

Note: Make sure *setup.py* is inside cloned repo. (which is by default in it)