# How to install Python package from GitHub?

Tags: python, pip

I want to use a new feature of httpie. This feature is in the github repo https://github.com/jkbr/httpie but not in the release on the python package index https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpie

How can I install the httpie package from the github repo? I tried

```
pip install https://github.com/jkbr/httpie
```

But I got  an error 'could not unpack'

---

In Nodejs, I can install packages from github like this

```
npm install git+https://github.com/substack/node-optimist.git
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github perhaps?

Answer (score 555, accepted):

You need to use the proper git URL:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git#egg=httpie
```

Also see the [*VCS Support* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/) of the pip documentation.

Don’t forget to include the `egg=<projectname>` part to [explicitly name the project](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#working-out-the-name-and-version); this way pip can track metadata for it without having to have run the setup.py script.

Comment: Another [installation option](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#installation) that doesn't require Git installed: `pip install --upgrade https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/tarball/master`

Comment: This also solved a problem for me installing a git-hosted package on www.pythonanywhere.com

Comment: Can I choose a branch?

Comment: @Nicofisi: yes, with `@<branchname>`  appended to the URL. See the [VCS support documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).

Comment: @JakubRoztocil - will it be always `https://github.com/[user]/[package name]/tarball/master`? I had to install one package from GitHub but didn't know what to type after `[package name]`. I tried `tarball/master` and it worked. I'm just wondering if it'll work each time.

Comment: @Konrad After `tarball` comes the reference. `master` is the name of the most common default branch, but the reference doesn’t have to be a branch name. You can also use tags or the SHA of a specific commit. Look at the specific repository to see what branches and tags they have.

Answer (score 136):

To install Python package from github, you need to clone that repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/jkbr/httpie.git
```

Then just run the setup.py file from that directory,

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: too often a python github repo does not have a setup.py file ... see  https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis

Comment: `pip install .` from the locally cloned repo dir will work too.

Comment: @ccpizza `Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`

Comment: @trthhrtz: this means that the package is not compliant and does not meet the requirements as defined in https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/

Comment: Install it in develop mode WITHOUT sudo:
run `pip install -e .` from inside the root dir of the cloned repo
There 2 benefits ot this solution:

1. You can install package in your home projects directory.
1. Package includes `.git` dir, so it's regular Git repository. You can push to your fork right away. [credit for this a goes to @avalanchy from the referred question]

Comment: getting the following error -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_trips'

Comment: I get `ImportError: cannot import name '<Thing>' from '<PackageName>' (unknown location)` when using either `sudo python setup.py install` or `pip install .` or `pip install -e .` and the way I solved this was by looking in `setup.py` and found that I could run `sudo python setup.py bdist_wheel` to generate the `.whl` file, and then `pip install path/to/the.whl` to install.