# Install pyHook 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyhook

I started coding with python about a month or so ago, and I've only just recently started using other modules within my code. I want to use pyHook for one of my projects. However, I've had no luck at finding a version of pyHook for python 3.5. There seems to be many people directing others to the following site:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

I have tried the files listed on the site, and they don't seem to be compatible with Python 3.5. Whenever I try to install the file using pip, I get the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: )
>   No matching distributions found for pyHook

I've seen videos of people installing pyHook from this site, and there are more versions no longer listed that are available for python 3.x. Why were they taken down, if anyone knows? I've tried downloading it from other sites, and they all seem to carry the same versions listed on this sight. How can I get the version I need? Or am I just installing it wrong and/or being stupid? If more info is needed, feel free to ask. Thanks  in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was asked quite a long time ago, and I have moved on since, but for any who may be experiencing this problem, it can be easily solved by going to the following link and installing the version of pyhook that will run for python 3.5. For 64-bit OS's, get pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl, and for 32 bit OS's get pyHook-1.5.1-cp35-none-win32.whl. Happy programming, all!

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k (see https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2crput/how_to_install_with_pip_directly_from_github/) unless you have already tried this and you had no luck.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. It ends up giving me a 404 error saying that there is no URL  https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k/zipball/master. There is a download link at the top right of the link you gave me where you can download it as a zip file. I tried replacing it with pip install (link), but it doesnt seem to work either. If you read through what it is doing in cmd, it says it is skipping a bunch of "optional fixers" if it helps any. It also says it is missing a file called "swig.exe". It then gives me a giant error that I think is saying it couldn't compile.

Comment: I've briefly skimmed the internet about installing modules within .zip files, but they seem complicated. If someone could give me a dummied-down explanation or any other way to install pyhook 3.x, please do so. Thanks!

Comment: Use the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github, it should guide through the install process.

Comment: Hi @thatoneguy245, I followed that but didn't work.

Error is `Cannot unpack file`, `cannot detect archive format`

https://pastebin.com/jYn1Pyk5