# django moderation compatibility with django 1.8

Tags: django

I am trying to install [django-moderation](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation) but it downgrades my Django installation from 1.8 to 1.6.

it seems that it is compatible with [django 1.8](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation/blob/master/tox.ini#L111).

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that it needs a [PyPi upgrade](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation/issues/147) ( current Pypi Version 0.3.5 ) and there is a ticket open to resolve that.

simple clone the repo and install it using `python setup.py install`, or use [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github) to install it.