# Install GitHub Repositories/Modules for python

Tags: git, python-3.x, github, pip, installation

I have searched for the last couple days on this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to install a pyttsx module for python 3.x, and have looked at multiple people saying I need to change the code in the **init**, engine, and driver files for the pyttsx module, which I have done, but pyttsx still doesn't seem to work. I am trying to install a module from [here](https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx), but I don't know how to install GitHub packages/repos to python. I have tried `pip install git+http://"URL_goes_here"`, but i can't seem to get it to work. I have the git client installed as well, which one of the answers said to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github).

I have python 3.x and windows 10.

Comment: Did you try with https? As in: `pip install git+https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx`.

Comment: Did you install the dependency (pywin32)? https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

Comment: @[VonC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) I get an error that says `could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32com (from pyttsx==1.2) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for win32com (from pyttsx==1.2)`

Comment: @Crt I just installed the dependency (I'm fairly certain it was installed correctly), and I still get the same error message as above

Answer (score 0):

This worked on Python 3 on Ubuntu:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx
```

But maybe it's not that easy on Windows to get the Engine running.