# Python 3.x: Error while installing 'forex-histdata-etl' from Github

Tags: git, python-3.x, github

I have been trying to install this [Python module](https://github.com/xeb/forex-histdata-etl) from GitHub using pip, but I keep getting a similar error message.

These are the lines I've used in the command prompt, all returning the same outcome:

1) `pip3 install https://github.com/xeb/forex-histdata-etl/tarball/master`

Error Message:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hb0mpr2y-build\

2) `pip3 install git+https://github.com/xeb/forex-histdata-etl.git`

Error Message:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wq0lx76w-build\

This is the first time I encounter this error, I already have a compatible version of git installed. I usually just go for "pip3 install module_name" and that's it, no complications, but this is the first time I do this for a Github file and I'd really like to solve this issue.

I also tried the suggestion from the last commentary of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github), where the user says we need to clone the repository and run a setup.py file of some kind. But can't find something like that in the module I'm trying to download/use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the repository doesn't have `setup.py` so it cannot be installed with `pip`. It's not a package.

The directory `tools` lacks `__init__.py` so it is not even a module.

It seems it's an application that have to be manually cloned and used using `make`. If you need to make some code from it a module you have to install it yourself.