# How to add a git clone command in Dockerfile

Tags: django, git, docker

I would like to clone a GitHub repo through my requirements.txt in Docker.

Actually the requirements file contains :

```
-e git://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git
Django==1.11.8
....
```

what is the specific command that I should add in Dockerfile to execute correctly the git clone command.

I tried `RUN git clone git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git` without any success.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python package from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

I simply modify my code from

`-e git://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git` to

`git+https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git` and it works great.