# Installing Pattern for Python 3

Tags: python, web

I have installed Python 3 via Anaconda 3 to my PC which runs Windows10.

In trying to install pattern I get an error message:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alienware\Documents>pip install pattern
Collecting pattern
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/50/d09941d53416f2a86676bd0dc341d5968b599a763b73f5d13f51c57b5641/pattern-2.6.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w36z8q7u\pattern\setup.py", line 40
        print n
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ALIENW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w36z8q7u\pattern\
```

Moreover at Github (https://github.com/clips/pattern) it is stated that:

> Pattern supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.6+. The Python 3 version is
>   currently only available on the development branch.

But how do I access the 'development branch'?

On the other hand, I have successfully installed pattern3 to use with Python 3 but I can not find documentation for pattern3 (compatible with Python 3) using Google.

### Update

@Roshan, I am running into an exception.  See below:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/clips/pattern/tree/development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python package from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github)

Comment: `git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern`

`cd pattern`

`python3.6 setup.py install`

Comment: above step will help in installation pattern

Comment: @ Roshan:  Thank you for the advice.  I run into an exception. Please see my post.