# Trying to install a tool from GitHub, but getting lots of errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install pdfminer from GitHub, and I am encountering some errors.

This threw an error:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
```

This threw an error:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
```

This threw an error:

```
git clone https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
```

I googled for a solution online and found the ideas, listed above, from here:
[How to install Python package from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github)

Those commands seemed to work for several other people, but these don't work for me.  I am trying to run these three commands in the Anaconda Prompt.  I am using Python 3.6.

Maybe something is not configured correctly on my side, but I can't imagine what it is.  Or, is it something else?

BTW, here are the errors that I get:

```
(base) C:\Users\Excel>pip install https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
Collecting https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
  Downloading https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
     \ 102kB 1.3MB/s
  Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-6kqx4igo\pdfmi
ner.six (downloaded from C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2bpsgsh
0, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-bui
ld-2bpsgsh0

(base) C:\Users\Excel>pip install git+https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
Collecting git+https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
  Cloning https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six to c:\users\excel\appdata\loc
al\temp\pip-req-build-iqvj3zbl
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing c
ommand git clone -q https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six C:\Users\Excel\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-iqvj3zbl
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

(base) C:\Users\Excel>git clone https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please show us the errors

Comment: Something ending with `.six` is unlikely to be a git repo. Can you link what you're trying to clone? (nevermind, I can see the link)

Comment: Note that you're getting the same "could not unpack" error as the question you linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python package from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're cloning the correct url. You're getting the same "could not unpack" error as the question you linked, hinting that it might be the exact same problem.

Try:

`pip install git+https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six.git`

or

`pip install git+git://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six.git`

Typically git repos end with `.git`, and when I added it to my clipboard from github that's the url I got.

You could also try `pip install pdfminer.six`, which I copied directly from their documentation: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ok, I finally got it to work.  First I had to download and install the Desktop from the link below.  https://desktop.github.com/  Then, follow the steps from the link below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows