# Setup tool install pylint for py2.75

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

Due to firewall blocked the pip installer , I have to download the tar file and use  setup tool to install package as below :

```
python setup.py install
```

My python version is py 2.75 so I choosed the pylint 1.9.3 according to instruction.
But it turns out below error message :

> Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?) No
>   local packages or download links found for pytest-runner Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 181, in 
>       install()   File "setup.py", line 178, in install
>       **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
>       _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 260, in
>   **init**
>       self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 284, in
>   fetch_build_eggs
>       parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 777,
>   in resolve
>       replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line
>   1060, in best_match
>       return self.obtain(req, installer)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line
>   1072, in obtain
>       return installer(requirement)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 327, in
>   fetch_build_egg
>       return cmd.easy_install(req)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 434, in easy_install
>       self.local_index   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line
>   475, in fetch_distribution
>       return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'

Comment: did you try using .whl files of setup

Comment: I tried, pip install xxx.whl, it turns out error message as below
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/isort/: .....
I think this is due to firewall

Comment: first try to clone from github using git...that install from that

Comment: @UmerFarooq  Thanks for tip, do you have link for detail instruction ?

Comment: just google the name of package along with GitHub you will find it....like: `pandas github`

Comment: also see this link also for installation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github

Comment: @UmerFarooq what's the difference between clone and download zip ?
After clone , I still have to run setup.py , right ?

Comment: difference me be the source you are use to download or clone.....yes...

Comment: @UmerFarooq 
it failed as below :  (is this connectivity issue ?)

$ git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint.git
Cloning into 'pylint'...
ls
remote: Enumerating objects: 52, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (52/52), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly86 MiB | 20.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: have you have git.....if there is problem while running git then there may be some problem due to firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is setuptools issue.
I reinstall the setuptools but it does not work.
Search for "easy_install" in Scripts folder, find some old easy_installxxx  pyc,py file/folder which is older than my reinstall date.
Delete them.
Reinstalled the setuptools

```
easy_install --version
```

It shows latest version now.
Then do again

```
python setup.py install
```

Now it works.