# i have problem with package installation deepmatcher

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, package, installation-package

hello i want to install python package **deepMatcher** i used pip command

pip install deepmatcher

get this error :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.3.0
>   (from deepmatcher) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1 No matching
>   distribution found for torch==0.3.0 (from deepmatcher)

**python 3;6**

**windows 10**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using torch try using 'torchtext==0.2.3' instead. Deepmatcher has a lot of dependency issues, especially with the torch package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10, but with fasttextmirror. The solution that worked for me was to run the following command:

`pip install git+https://github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher#egg=deepmatcher`

Credits to SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268990/2516301