# Private Github python repo cannot be installed

Tags: python, github, pip, repository, installation

I want to install [this Python package](https://github.com/nealjean/coreg) from a private repository.

I tried multiple ways addressed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2crput/how_to_install_with_pip_directly_from_github/).

However, I got following errors:

1.

```
MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ pip install https://github.com/nealjean/coreg.git

Collecting https://github.com/nealjean/coreg.git
  Downloading https://github.com/nealjean/coreg.git
 \ 102kB 955kB/s
ERROR: Cannot unpack file /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-unpack-hl6ejff8/coreg.git 
(downloaded from /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-0xy7h6hv, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); 
cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-0xy7h6hv
```

2.

```
MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ pip install git+https://github.com/nealjean/coreg

Collecting git+https://github.com/nealjean/coreg
Cloning https://github.com/nealjean/coreg to /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-zvs4cg3t
Running command git clone -q https://github.com/nealjean/coreg /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-zvs4cg3t
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/makotomiyazaki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-zvs4cg3t/setup.py'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_f/ds87hcrj1d3023gdtg72nb7w0000gn/T/pip-req-build-zvs4cg3t/
```

3.

```
MakotonoMacBook-ea:~ makotomiyazaki$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/nealjean/coreg
ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/nealjean/coreg', 
please specify one with #egg=your_package_name
```

I referred to several other methods suggested such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github), but didn't solve my problem.
Does anyone know the cause and the solutions?
I am using Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The repository](https://github.com/nealjean/coreg) doesn't have `setup.py`, it cannot be installed with `pip`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, in this case how can I install? Could you provide me any guides or tutorials?

Comment: Why not ask the author? Create an issue, for example, asking how to install without `setup.py`.