# How to set up private python project for people to pip install?

Tags: python

I have a python package project 'webapi' and I want to set up in a way so that other people can "pip install webapi". If I want to put it on a private server with a specific ip: xx.xx.xx.xx.
So other people with the access right don't need to git clone the project and install it locally into their virtual environment. Instead, they can simply do:

```
pip install webapi
```

And they can start to use it, just as use other public python libraries. In order to do this, how can I start with this? Is there some tutorial to help with this? I tried a few keywords to search for instruction, but haven't found something useful.

Comment: Quick search shows [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/project-management/how-to-create-a-private-python-package-repository/) but someone else may have a better idea.

Comment: You can also use pip to install directly from a github repo https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268990/7284763

Comment: @steviestickman or any git repo, doesn't have to be github. OP could set up a git server for people to run pip against.

Comment: I believe the question asked just needs some rewording. I understand @marlon asking, "How do I setup a A minimal PyPI server for use with pip/easy_install for access only to users on a private network?"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is unclear, if you want to upload your webapi package to PyPi you can read [this article](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56). But this will make your package public and i'm not quite sure that's what you want.
If what you want is a private pypi server then checkout this package [private-pypi](https://pypi.org/project/private-pypi/). There's a whole description of how to set your server and use it in the documentation.

Comment: I want something similar to PyPi, but it has to be private. For example, on a company's server.

Comment: well that's exactly what private-pypi does

Comment: @marlon , follow the install instructions on the company server that is only accessible by authorized users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a software repository management application such as [Pulp](https://pulpproject.org/) take a look at [their plugin section](https://pulpproject.org/content-plugins/) and their documentation is [here](https://pulp-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I use it as a private python repository for systems that for security reason are isolated from the internet but it can also host your own custom Python packages.

Answer (score 0):

Linode provides another way of setting up a private pip repos. Most important is to work with your team to decide which package dependencies that need to be maintained.

[guides/how-to-create-a-private-python-package-repository/](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-create-a-private-python-package-repository/)