# Cannot locate the .so file in a package installed from git

Tags: python, git, pip, .so

I am trying to install a python package from gitlab. I am using `pip install git+gitlab_package_address`,  [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github). After that, I am able to import the package. But the package comes with an .so file and later it throws an error: `OSError: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH/lib{that_package}.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Manual trial: I can clone the repo via SSH and move into the repo directory. Compile to get the desired `lib{that_package}.so` (checked that it exists using `ls`) and using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolute/path/to/the/repo/directory`. Still the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.so` files are architecture dependent; do you know that it was compiled for your OS and hardware?

Comment: No how to check that: I can manually compile the c code present in the src with ```gcc``` without an issue. Does that mean it is fine with my OS and hardware?

Comment: When you compile with `gcc` you are generating a new file. What I'm trying to say is that if the Git repo contained a compiled `.so` file, that is not guaranteed to work on your computer; but if you managed to recompile it locally, that would not be an issue.

Comment: Is the error message literal? That looks like it tried to access a directory named `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` rather than expand the value of the variable with that name.

Comment: It's the ```OSError```.. so I guess it wants access to the library (but could never find it)

Comment: We'd really need to see more debugging details to see where things are going wrong and what exactly you have done so far.

Comment: Since `.so` files are build artifacts, they should rarely if ever be put in a repository in the first place. That's probably the (or a) root problem: the package is distributed with a `.so` file but should not be. The `$` sign in the error message suggests additional errors.

Comment: Ya.. I understand the points raised above. It seems that is some issue with git repo's packaging. I am able to do a workaround: I replaced the ```$LD_LIBRARY_PATH/lib{the_package}.so``` with the absolute path of the ```lib{the_package}.so``` (in a file which had this line). And ran the ```setup.py``` again. Now this works.. but is not a solution I was looking for.