# Installing non-pip library in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I am using a module which is not recognised by pip so cannot be called as a dependency from a requirements file. The module in question is a registration backend: https://github.com/georgema1982/django-insensitive

Where should I install this so that e.g. a Heroku environment can access it? I have installed it in my virtualenv site packages but that's no good when deployed. I'm guessing I'll have to push it up with git. Even then, where's best to keep it my project and how should I refer to it in the settings file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github

Comment: very nice thanks. That answer led me on the right path. I actually needed the requirements file code specifically which turned out to be: `-e git://github.com/georgema1982/django-insensitive.git#egg=django-insensitive`

Comment: Add your own answer if you've fixed the issue so that the question will be marked as solved