# Managing github dependencies in virtualenv

Tags: python, github, virtualenv

After I pip installed a python package from a github repo into my virtualenv, I made some changes to it. How should I set it up so that I can also merge changes from the original repo?

Currently, I forked the original repo, but the fork is not hooked up with the copy in my virtualenv, so every time I make changes in the virtualenv, I have to copy manually to the fork, and vice versa if I pull changes from the original repo to my fork.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to be more organised here. You should merge changes in the original github repo into your fork and only install into your virtualenv via your fork. This question shows how to install via Github using pip - [Configuring so that pip install can work from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github)

If you make local changes to the library/software in your virtual env, you should merge the changes into your fork of the repo and then install from it. Your question only seems to concern organising changes from different sources (your own, changes from upstream). All these can generally be solved satisfactorily with a good workflow as described earlier.

Comment: My install is the same as the link you provided. Mainly, I am not sure how to connect the fork to the folder in my virtualenv that is installed via pip from the fork, so that I can push changes between them.