# pip install github repository fails: No files/directories

Tags: python, git, pip

I'm working on python module, I host it on Github.

For a test, I tried to install it with `pip`.

I tried several ways that I've seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github).

Everytime I get an error from running:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module
```

And the output :

```
Collecting git+git://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module
Cloning git://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module to /tmp/pip-HbjLru-build
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-HbjLru-build/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

**Or**

```
pip install https://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module
```

Output :

```
Collecting https://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:      

InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. 
For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
 InsecurePlatformWarning
 Downloading https://github.com/amiceli/i2c-module
 - 36kB 328kB/s
Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-3Qo8KK-unpack/i2c-module (downloaded from /tmp/pip-KnZ537-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-KnZ537-build
```

**Or again :**

```
pip install git+git://github.com:amiceli/i2c-module.git
```

Output :

```
Collecting git+git://github.com:amiceli/i2c-module.git
Cloning git://github.com:amiceli/i2c-module.git to /tmp/pip-d7KPkA-build
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com: Servname() n'est pas support?e pour ai_socktype

Complete output from command git clone -q git://github.com:amiceli/i2c-module.git /tmp/pip-d7KPkA-build:

 ----------------------------------------
Command "git clone -q git://github.com:amiceli/i2c-module.git /tmp/pip-d7KPkA-build" failed with error code 128 in None
```

**EDIT**

I've a new bug. I've installed the module, it works.

But when I try to import it, I've a `No module named error`.

When I try `pip freeze` I can see the module in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the Github repository is not a Python package. `setup.py` says:

```
  print ('install i2c')
```

[Please read official packaging guide how to create a proper Python package](http://packaging.python.org/).