# Issue importing a repo from github

Tags: python, pip

Everytime I try to import this repo

```
https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/blob/7b0d51cca7e75b3cf84f5dbb74e76f727816e50d/mavutil.py
```

Using the following

```
pip install https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink.git
```

However, I am getting this error.

```
Collecting https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink.git
  Downloading https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink.git
  Cannot unpack file c:\users\mike\appdata\local\temp\pip-l_8clc-unpack\pymavlink.git (downloaded from c:\users\mike\appdata\local\temp\pip-nww8fs-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of c:\users\mike\appdata\local\temp\pip-nww8fs-build
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github

Answer (score 3):

Try `pip install git+https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink.git`. This tells pip it's a git archive.
Otherwise, you could always just use the github archive directly: `pip install https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/archive/master.zip`

Comment: The first one gives me an error of: Cannot find command 'git', the 2nd one gives me an error of  ImportError: No module named future; Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

Comment: For the first one, you don't have git installed or in your PATH.

Comment: I just installed it and ran it on cmd and got this error: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1