# install Numberjack on python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to use Constraint Programming in Python and so I am trying to install the Numberjack standard package from Github.
I downloaded the archive but i don't know what to do with it. Someone can help me?

I am using windows

I tried the command that you suggest to me but i got this error

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ixtvck33\Numberjack\

Comment: go to the command line, type `pip install Numberjack` then it will install Numberjack for your python distribution along with any dependencies the package requires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring so that pip install can work from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github)

Comment: No need to install from GitHub. See https://pypi.org/project/Numberjack/

Comment: when i use that command i have an error: "colud not find xml2-config"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install by cloning the report, Do the following

git clone

then do the following

```
cd Numberjack

python setup.py build

python setup.py install
```

Comment: because i have the error "colud not find xml2-config"