# Import error after successfully installing glove

Tags: python, glove

I have successfully installed glove. After running 
`pip3 install https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/glove/archive/master.zip` from the command line I get the following message

```
Collecting https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/glove/archive/master.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/glove/archive/master.zip
     - 10kB 15.6MB/s
Collecting cython (from glove==1.0.1)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/e6/6e30303d7bc17289411d82276b7338a1781964171c94f5ebe689cbecad4c/Cython-0.29.14-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.9MB 4.6MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from glove==1.0.1) (1.17.3)
Installing collected packages: cython, glove
  Running setup.py install for glove ... done
Successfully installed cython-0.29.14 glove-1.0.1
```

However when trying to `import glove` within my python shell I get the module not found error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glove'
```

Any fixes for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring so that pip install can work from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github)

Comment: Search for "ImportError" with "successfully installed".  There are many possibilities for this.  Most likely you are using the wrong pip or the wrong Python.  To be sure, instead of running just `pip`, instead run `python -m pip` where "python" is replaced by whatever Python you want to install the module with (i.e. you have multiple Python installations on your system; make sure you're using the right one).