# Get new commits from a git repo installed with pip in a conda environment when updating

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am using a YAML config to install a package from BitBucket into my conda environment, a subset of the file looks like this:

```
# config.yaml

name: ll4ma_opt
channels:
- defaults
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- pip
- pip:
  - git+https://bitbucket.org/robot-learning/ll4ma_util.git
```

This works great. I do `conda env create -f config.yaml` and it creates the environment just fine.

My problem is that when I make a change to the BitBucket package `ll4ma_util`, I do not get those changes in my conda environment, even after doing `conda env update -f config.yaml`

I see this output in the terminal when I try to do the update:

```
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting git+https://bitbucket.org/robot-learning/ll4ma_util.git (from -r /home/adam/ll4ma-opt-sandbox/conda/condaenv.65mn0x4h.requirements.txt (line 3))
  Cloning https://bitbucket.org/robot-learning/ll4ma_util.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-5qdqlgww
  Resolved https://bitbucket.org/robot-learning/ll4ma_util.git to commit 9673a4ff2025356a4eff72b0ee44e7f02d76b414
```

The hash shown is in fact the latest commit, but when I try to use the code after the update it's still using the old code and doesn't reflect the changes I made to the `ll4ma_util` package. The only way I've been successful is to completely remove my environment with `conda env remove -n ll4ma_opt` and then create it new again.

Is there a way I can force an update of the BitBucket package such that if I installed the package using `git` and `pip` in the conda environment, it will pull and use any recent changes from the git repo when I run an update of my conda environment?

Comment: @merv you're right that was a key thing I was missing, with the `-e` flag it creates a local version that pulls the changes. If you make an answer I can mark accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39016761/570918), to have a Pip install that respects file changes (such as repository pulls), one needs the `-e` flag. In the Conda YAML context, you'd want:

```yaml
name: ll4ma_opt
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -e git+https://bitbucket.org/robot-learning/ll4ma_util.git
```