# Updating pip installed package from git

Tags: python, git, pip

I know that one can pip install directly via github so long as the github repo is set up correctly for installation. For example:

```sh
pip install git+https://git.example.com/MyProject
```

I went through the relevant section in the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/?highlight=git%2B#git) but didn't find any information regarding updating. I've also read through two other related threads ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github)) on pip installing via Github, but they also didn't mention about updating. It was tempting to try

```sh
pip install -U git+https://git.example.com/MyProject
```

where `-U` stands for update, but I'm not sure will this work. Has anyone tried something like this before?

Comment: You can update from a git repo. Why not give it a try!

Comment: Do you have python installed? You can download the script they reference in the guide and then run `python get-pip.py`. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py

Comment: I have the same problem and it only works with `-U --force-reinstall`.