# pywin32 installed files different than souce files on github

Tags: python, pip, pywin32, python-3.11

I had an issue with Mark Hammond's `pythonwin` install for 3.11.2

I traced the issue to a line of code in the file `CallTips.py` that was using the deprecated `inspect.formatargspecs()` and posted an issue on GitHub

I subsequently discovered that the code in the github source https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/Pythonwin/pywin/idle/CallTips.py fixes the issue (line 132) using `inspect.signature()` and was able to repair my installed file.

However, I am curious how I might be able to debug what went wrong with the install (old files using deprecated python methods) ... I used the recommended `python -m pip install pywin32 --upgrade`

The pip project is here: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/305/

My 2 part github issue is here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/2020

Comment: Well clearly the version you're getting from pip/PyPi is not the version in GitHub. The GitHub file shows that it was last modified only 2 weeks ago, yet the [version history in PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/305/#history) only goes up to 6 November 2022. So, I guess they didn't put together a release, but you can just [install straight from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247605/configuring-so-that-pip-install-can-work-from-github).

Comment: This is the file you must look at: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/b305/Pythonwin/pywin/idle/CallTips.py. A release is a snapshot of the branch it was made from (whether it's  *main* (*master*)  or other) at a given time. The bug you submitted is invalid (it only shows that you're unfamiliar with how releases are made).

Comment: @CristiFati ... i contend that the submission to GitHub (if you include the edited original and the comment) was accurate .... my install (using the recommended method) installed buggy code (because it used deprecated funtionality) ... the whole point of my posting this on stackoverflow is to gain insight into the release process ... i would like to figure out, by looking at the pip source, where the package was pulling it's source from ... another possibility is that i performed the install wrong ..

Comment: @CristiFati i closed the issue on GitHub thanks to your comment ... appreciate it .. i learned something ... i did think you were condescending ... if it was intentional, sorry for you ... if it was a misread by me, i apologize

Comment: There's the *PR* which fixed the issue: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1975. And *BTW* your comment on *GitHub* doesn't help you (or anyone else). Generally, people should do their homework before posting. It wasn;t my intention to be condescending.

Comment: @CristiFati ... Please advise ... i thought i did a ton of homework ... i found a real issue that only recently had been fixed but not yet implemented in a release and was thrust into a whole new domain of release processes that was non-obvious ... i used stackoverflow to help me resolve the non-obvious problem ... i'm not sure what was expected of me

Answer (score 0):

with help from comments, i was able to get the info i was requesting ... the bugfix on GitHub was subsequent to the most recent version in PyPi

i don't think the answer was obvious to someone with no experience releasing code or using GitHub though i certainly could have come up with the answer on my own ...

summarizing

the release info for the PyPi can be ascertained from the project homepage but it is easier to see by clicking 'Release history' ... doing so reveals the release as made on Nov. 6, 2022

i couldn't find a direct link to the GitHub tag for the code that was packaged but there are links to the GitHub project

from the GitHub project, i clicked on 'tags' to find 'b305' from Nov 6.

clicking on 'b305' and then 'code' gets to the code that was packaged in the release and is erroneous

i found that there was a fix through a different path starting with navigating the the current version of the file that had been buggy, clicking on 'history' to find that the bug was fixed on Nov 27

one final thing, i did try searching for the bug in issues but was unsuccessful and thus started my journey of filing and ultimately closing an issue

i would appreciate feedback as to whether this answer is useful and suggestions on how to document a series of clicks on hyperlinks

Comment: It would be useful if you also included the *URL*s you mentioned.