# What is the difference between import a module from a folder and import a module from a package?

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I need to better understand the difference between a normal directory and a Python package. I know this sentence present in the Python documentation about [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and in particular in the paragraph about [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.

To explain my doubt I'll show an example of directory structure:

```
study_import
  |-folder1
  |   |-b.py
  |-a.py
```

The content of the module `study_import/a.py` is:

```
import folder1.b
print(folder1.b.VAR2)
```

The content of the module `study_import/folder1/b.py` is:

```
VAR2="20"
```

The module `a.py` imports the module `b.py` from the directory `folder1` and can be executed correctly. Its output is the printout of the number `20`.

With the previous folder structure `study_import` and `folder1` are not packages because they don't contain the file `__init__.py`.

In this moment I don't understand the need to have a package because for example the instruction `import folder1.b` can be executed even the `__init__.py` there isn't present.
**Until now I thought that packages were needed to correctly import modules.**

Could someone help me to understand what is the difference between import a module from a folder and import a module from a package?

---

**EDIT**: I have followed the hint of Brian61354270 so I add 2 `print()` instructions in `study_import/a.py`:

```
import folder1.b

print(folder1.b.VAR2)
print(folder1)
print(folder1.b)
```

If I execute the script `a.py` the output is:

```
20
<module 'folder1' (namespace)>
<module 'folder1.b' from '/path/to/study_import/folder1/b.py'>
```

### `folder1` becomes a package

I add the file `__init__.py` in `folder1` ===> `folder1` becomes a package:

```
study_import
  |-folder1
  |   |-__init__.py
  |   |-b.py
  |-a.py
```

Now the execution of the script `a.py` produces the followed output:

```
20
<module 'folder1' from '/path/to/study_import/folder1/__init__.py'>
<module 'folder1.b' from '/path/to/study_import/folder1/b.py'>
```

Can someone explain the difference between 2 outputs?

Comment: Run `import folder1.b` and compare `print(folder1)` to `print(folder1.b)`. You've discovered the difference between (import) packages and [implicit namespace packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python) Also [Namespace vs regular package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21819649/11082165) and [Python Namespace Packages in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41621131/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270 So packaging is linked only with namespace and not to import instruction?

Comment: Until now I was convinced that packages are needed to have a correct import but the example in my question seems to tell the opposite.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Packages are needed for imports (by definition). However, Python let's you implicitly define namespace packages by placing directories _without_ `__init__.py` files on the Python path. Namespace packages behave differently from "normal" import packages in several key ways, so it's worth figuring out which you actually want