# Python: Importing a package in another package without using the full path

Tags: python, import, module, package, pythonpath

I have some code that I can't get to import correctly [on Linux]:

Files (every python file contains just a class by the same name and capitalization):

```
commandreader/
|-- CommandReader.py
|-- y/
    |-- Switch.py
    |-- Option.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- x/
        |-- InputArg.py
        |-- __init__.py
```

CommandReader.py's import:

```
from y import Switch
from y import Option
```

y/Switch.py's and y/Option.py's import:

```
from x import InputArg
```

y/__init__.py:

```
from .import x
from .Switch import Switch
from .Option import Option
```

y/x/__init__.py:

```
from .InputArg import InputArg
```

Error:

```
$ python3 ./CommandReader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CommandReader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from y import Switch
  File "/home/swatts/code/commandreader/y/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .Switch import Switch
  File "/home/swatts/code/commandreader/y/Switch.py", line 8, in <module>
    from x import InputArg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x'
```

Edit: Along with my error, do I misunderstand how Python wants packages to work? Because that's the impression I'm under.

Comment: What happens if you run `python3 -m CommandReader` instead? I would recommend using absolute imports first, and then eventually switch to relative once everything works well. See eventually this answer on a relatively similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59768291/11138259

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution is, You can add the path of module in environmental variables:

Add the path in `Path` which is in `Environmental Variable`

If you are using `Windows`

1. Right click on `My Computer` and go to `Properties`
2. Select `Advanced system settings`
3. Go to Tab `Advanced`
4. Click on `Environment Variables`
5. In `System Variables` Section Search for `Path` Variable
6. Double click on it and add the path in the list of its `value` field.

You can also do using code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path)
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: I am using Linux, and doesn't it seem like overkill to change an environment variable just to get this working, or do I just misunderstand how Python wants packages to be done?

Comment: You need to specify the path of the module in the code if you don't want to alter the environment variables because python needs the references of that modules like from where the module is coming.Check this link. This might help you. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Gotcha, so Python doesn't support importing as I was trying to do in a manner similar to Java.

Comment: I really doubt it is necessary to do these steps. As far I know, it is (almost) never necessary to modify `sys.path` or the environment variable`PYTHONPATH`. Instead in this case, it would probably be better to run code with `python -m CommandReader`, and change all imports to absolute imports. Then eventually once it's stable, progressively change back to relative imports if needed.