# Python argparse: accessing the same ArgumentParser/argument in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a script, `main.py`, that sets up an `argumentParser()` object to read in `commandline` arguments before calling a `main()` file that lives in another module, `alation_cronjob.py`.

in **main.py**. I actually made `make_parser()` based on other suggestions, originally there was only `configure_and_run()`. So not as much thought has been put towards how this file is currently organized. I have also omitted multiple other arguments from this code snippet that aren't really relevant.

```
from mypkg.alation_cronjob import main

def make_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-v", "--verbose", help="Increase verbosity of output", action="store_true"
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--alation-instance",
        type=str,
        choices=["prod", "dev"],
        required=True,
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

def configure_and_run():

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    args = make_parser()

    if args.verbose:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logging.debug("Verbose output enabled.")

    main(
        alation_instance=args.alation_instance,
        consul_url=args.consul_url,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_and_run()
```

in **alation_cronjob.py** where main() lives, at the top of the file is the import of another script called alation.py.

```
from mypkg.alation import delete_article, find_article_by_title, update_existing_article
```

Meanwhile, in **alation.py**

```
from utils.get_refresh_token import get_refresh_token
from utils.get_access_token import get_access_token

access_token = get_access_token(get_refresh_token())
```

So the problem is that. I need to access `args.alation_instance` in `utils.get_refresh_token().` I know that one workaround is to use sys.argv, though I'd have to add some extra code to make sure I select the alation_instance argument specifically. I also know i can add an ArgumentParser() to utils.create_refresh_token.py, but I would also have to add in all the other arguments provided in main.py including ones I don't intend to use in utils.create_refresh_token. The onlly argument I want is args.alation_instance.

Is there an easy way to achieve that? I expect that I'll have to refactor this code, I'm just looking for the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: You could just assign the parsed `args` to a global in a shared module (`mypkg.config`?)

Comment: @AKX do you mean going for something along the lines of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17175452/6432861 . So let's say I make another package/directory, put a file in it called parse.py that has make_parser() inside of it. Then call that in main.py to have it make args? Then I would be able to import make_parser in utils/get_refresh_token.py?

Comment: `make_parser` should focus on *making* the parser, rather than making the parser *and* parsing arguments. If it just returns the `ArgumentParser` instance, you can call its `parse_args` method as many times as you like, with whatever arguments you want (you can pass a list of strings to parse, rather than just parsing `sys.argv[1:]` by default).

Comment: I would put code `access_token = get_access_token(get_refresh_token())`
in function and later execute it manually in main code. And I would send `args` to this function as parameter - `alation.my_function(args)`. Frankly all code in other modules I would put in functions to control when it is executed and what values it can get. Putting code directly in file is wrong idea.