# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to install python packages from github. Whenever I try to install any package I get error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte". I have tried looking for answers to similar problems but no luck. I will be grateful for any help regarding this issue.
Error screenshot link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc2i5cpi5wcyr3q/error%20install.png?dl=0

Comment: I'm seeing this in a library using python Requests. The `0x8b` comes from the gzip header: `1F 8B 08`.  Something is missing the fact that this is gzip-compressed data.

Answer (score 4):

You can't install a package by using:

```
pip install https://github.com/Theano/Theano
```

Instead you should use:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

if you want to install from Github. If you want to install the package from PyPI you should use:

```
pip install Theano
```

Comment: The installation method used is the same as mentioned in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322334/how-to-use-python-pip-install-software-to-pull-packages-from-github" and I succeeded in installing it before but now it is not working. One thing that I should have mentioned earlier is I am using anaconda ver 2.1.