# Decoding QR code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code

I am trying to read QR codes using python3. I've found different solutions that depend on using qrtools.

I've also tried to download it using pip3 or apt-get. Then I've tried to install it from sources, tried to install zbar lib which it use to work, but I had multiple errors.

I've also tried to download and use it in python2, and it works successfully. And I want to ask, can I use it in python3, or it is impossible?

Comment: Looking at qrtools docs it seems Python3 is supported. I suggest you file a bug report to the developers with a full error description included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the question: zbar QR code reader in python 3 in google. There is an library that does this. Download the follow library in pip install. ZBar it self is only for python 2, but the zbarlight also for python 3.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbarlight

**edit:**
My answer would be usefull: 
[How to use Python Pip install software, to pull packages from Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322334/how-to-use-python-pip-install-software-to-pull-packages-from-github/30436019#30436019)

Comment: Thanks for response, but I think the biggest problem is to install zbar library.

Comment: You don't need then zbar library but the zbarlight library in python 3

Comment: After install, I try to import it, but have this:
ImportError: No module named 'zbarlight._zbarlight' is it normal, or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: yes, you doing something wrong, did you do : pip install zbarlight

Comment: Wow, I don't know why, but when I tried it in console using python3 it gave me an exception. When I used it in PyCharm, its ok. So, thank you very much @Martijn van Wezel

Answer (score 3):

I have used `pyzbar` for reading my QR codes in Python3.

Installation:

```
brew install zbar
pip install pyqrcode
pip install pyzbar
```

And for reading the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode


result = decode(Image.open('sample.png'))
print(result)
```